# A faster way to generate bitmaps using GDI+

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I'm using the GDI+ class to draw some Bitmaps on a form for a game I'm trying to program. I want to speed up my game, so I thought about preventing drawing a pixel more than once.

For example:

I'll draw a 100x100 image at (10,10) and another 100x100 image at (20,20).

I want to prevent drawing in the region of the old image (from (10,10) to (110,100)) and only draw in the blank pixels (from (110,110) to (120,120)).

I'm trying to speed up the drawing event as if there is a background and several images. Then I want to draw the background, rest of pixels which are not colored.

I'm using VB.NET 2005

Helping Images:-
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#82i5t1w99v7mdf1
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#p7d4fpdcoap51nd

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can you post some code?

Comment: Khalid, I tried to clean up the English, but I'm not sure I conveyed exactly what you meant (it was very hard for me to understand). Can you review the edit and make sure I got it right? (Some example code, or maybe images, would help)

Comment: Ok , I'll try to help you understanding me
this is the first image :-
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#82i5t1w99v7mdf1
the second :-
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#p7d4fpdcoap51nd
hope this better

Comment: try to add some code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the image using the [Graphics.DrawImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040.aspx) overload which allows you to specify a `Rectangle` for the portion of the image to draw.  This will allow you to only draw a 10x10 pixel portion of the image each time.

Comment: I'm sorry but this won't help any